# How do you specify BGP Authentication Key when using Verizon's Secure Cloud Interconnect?

Tags: bgp

I am trying to establish a Direct Connect Link using Verizon's Secure Cloud Interconnect service.

I have established the connection in the Dynamic Network Manager on the Verizon side and the VIFs appear in my target account and all is looking good up to that point. The problem is that the BGP status is down. When using the awscli to describe the VIF, I see that there is no AuthKey in my BgpPeers that where created and I believe this is preventing the BGP session establishment.

My question is: How do you specify the BGP Authentication Key when creating a VIF through Verizon's Dynamic Network Manager/Secure Cloud Interconnect ?

Comment: It is hard to answer this question, I hardly understand what you want. It is very Verizon specific and I have found the same question over here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53837376/establishing-bgp-session-using-verizons-secure-cloud-interconnect

Comment: I’d advise you reach out to your Verizon SE and you may also debug the BGP neighbor to determine the reason for the adjacency failing.